# All http redirects to https://homepage.com

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-ce

my Magento site 1.9.2.4 redirects all users from http://example.com/foo to https://example.com.

How do I change this to redirect to https://example.com/foo?

I looked at .htaccess in my document root and I can't tell why they're being redirected in the first place. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add more details.  Like: Is this an old site?  Was this recently installed?  What did you do before this happened?  Can you access the admin?

Comment: It sounds like your secure url and unsecure base urls are the same in System>Config>General>Web . Can you confirm that?

Comment: @jscar Yes, the secure url and unsecure base url's are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in htaccess you should have a mod_rewrite section that starts with `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`
Soon after that there should be a line that says `RewriteEngine on`

After that you need to put the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Because the secure url and unsecure base urls are the same in Magento admin it is redirecting all traffic to https but it is redirecting traffic to direct URLs to the base URL as you are experiencing. The rule in htaccess will make sure that they are just redirected to the same url but over https.

Please try this on a dev site first.

Comment: When I put this in .htaccess it worked: RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

In case you are on nginx environment, here is the vhost configuration :

server {

```
listen 80;
server_name www.test.com test.com;
return 301 https://www.test.com$request_uri;
```

}

server {

```
listen 443 ssl;
...
...
...
```

}